# How to convert WPF Desktop app into Native exe?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, native

I am beginner at C# WPF app development. I have built a very small application using C#, Wpf, Sqlite. The application is working properly in my machine.

But I want to convert into Native binary. I have learned about .NET Native. But Do not know how to convert into the application into native executable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Given that .NET Native isn't released yet, why are you trying to use it at all? If you want to create a single executable, in .NET 5 you create a single file executable, either self contained (ie includes the runtime) or not

Comment: Or perhaps I should say that what started as .NET Native ended up having such a narrow scope (UWP precompilation only) that most developers forgot about it, and due to .NET Core even that precompilation technology will have to change

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to rewrite the entire application into using UWP (Universal Windows Platform).

I wouldn't stress using .NET Native over .NET.
Although you'd see performance increases and reduced memory consumption, I doubt you'll truly benefit from it where you're currently at.

Don't let the OS/Compiler make bad code good. Focus on writing good code that's fast regardless if it's native or not.

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to convert into Native binary.

It's unclear what you mean by "native" here but if you target .NET Core you could publish your app as [self-contained platform-specific executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077#publish-self-contained) that runs on any supported Windows machine.

The output publishing folder of a self-contained app contains all components of the app, including the .NET Core libraries and target runtime so you don't have to pre-install these on the client computer(s).

If you want to decrease the JIT compilation time, there is also a `PublishReadyToRun` option that can be used:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 -p:PublishReadyToRun=true
```

The .NET Native toolchain applies to Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps only.